# How to create a Twitter Heron project using IntelliJ IDEA on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, project, intellij-14, heron

I want to create a Twitter Heron project using IntelliJ IDEA on Windows 10. But I cannot find tutorials about it.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple Maven-based starter project that you can clone and use [here](https://github.com/streamlio/heron-java-streamlet-api-example).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/streamlio/heron-java-streamlet-api-example
```

To use the starter in IntelliJ, just click **Import Project**, select the cloned directory, select "Maven" under **Import project from external model**, and IntelliJ should take care of the rest. Feel free to respond if you run into any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help so much. I have imported your project into IntelliJ IEDA. And when I try to run the example : **WordCountStreamletTopology**,   the exception happened as following:   **`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Linking with Kryo is needed because setTopologySerializer is used at com.twitter.heron.streamlet.Config$Builder.applySerializer(Config.java:155)'**  Can you give me some suggestion about this problem?

Comment: An other questions: Should I deployed Heron on my windows computer before I running the heron example? I have deployed local heron on my Liunx Virtual computer, but I don't know how to deploy it on windows OS...

Comment: @YitianZhang I've made some changes to that repository that should fix the issue that you ran into. Follow the instructions one more time (and make sure that you pull the most recent `master`) and let me know if the problem persists. As for Windows, please know that Heron is not currently supported on Windows.